# MySQL: updating a row and deleting the original in case it becomes a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, duplicates

I have a simple `table` made up of two columns: `col_A` and `col_B`.

**The primary key is defined over both.**

I need to update some rows and assign to `col_A` values that may generate duplicates, for example:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col_A` = 66 WHERE `col_A` = 70
```

This statement sometimes yields a duplicate key error.

I don't want to simply ignore the error with `UPDATE IGNORE`, because then the rows that generate the error would remain unchanged. Instead, **I want them to be deleted when they would conflict with another row after they have been updated**

I'd like to write something like:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col_A` = 66 WHERE `col_A` = 70 ON DUPLICATE KEY REPLACE
```

which unfortunately isn't legal in SQL, so I need help finding another way around.
Also, I'm using PHP and could consider a hybrid solution (i.e. part query part php code), but keep in mind that I have to perform this updating operation many millions of times.

thanks for your attention,

Silvio

Reminder: `UPDATE`'s syntax has problems with joins with the same table that is being updated

**EDIT**: sorry, the column name in the WHERE clause was wrong, now I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to revised question:

```
DELETE FROM
    table_A
USING
    table AS table_A
    JOIN table AS table_B ON
        table_A.col_B = table_B.col_B AND
        table_B.col_A = 70
WHERE
    table_A.col_A = 66
```

This gets rid of the rows that would cause problems. Then you issue your `UPDATE` query. Ideally you will do it all inside a transaction to avoid a situation where troublesome rows are re-inserted in between the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any foreign keys referencing this table? If not then the following should do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `MyProcedure` (IN invarA INT, IN invarB INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table WHERE col_B = invarB;
    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO table (`col_A`, `col_B`) VALUES (invarA, invarB);
    END IF;
END
```

Example call:

```
CALL `MyProcedure`(66, 70)
```

Comment: This answer was posted before the edit to the question. It is not a suitable answer to the revised question.